# Get array key value from JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have one JSON object as below

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Result:

```
{
  "e": {
    "name": "tushar",
    "id": "123",
    "tag": {}
  }
}
```

Now I want name and id from above object. How to get array key value from JSON object?

```
dp.onEventClick = function(args) {

                 console.log(JSON.stringify(args.e.name));


            };
```

this is my function.

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: How can I get name "tushar" in one variable and id 123 in other variable

Comment: you mean `obj.e.name` `obj.e.id` ?

Comment: `obj.e.name` and `obj.e.id`?

Comment: I have tried obj.e.name but its shows undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using : `JSON.stringify(obj.e.name)`

`console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.e))` will give you:

```
{
    "name": "tushar",
    "id": "123",
    "tag": {}
}
```

And `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.e.name))` will gives you the desired output: `tushar` and so on.

```js
var object = JSON.parse('{"e":{"name":"tushar","id":"123","tag":{}}}');
console.log(object.e.name);
```

TYPE OF data your are receiving:

```js
var args = JSON.parse('{"e":{"name":"tushar","id":"123","tag":{}}}');
console.log(typeof(args.e));
obj = JSON.stringify(args.e);
console.log(typeof(obj));
```

**You cant do like below:**

```
var args = JSON.parse('{"e":{"name":"tushar","id":"123","tag":{}}}');
var obj = JSON.stringify(args.e); // Here obj is a string
console.log(obj.name); // You cant do like this
```

Because now `obj` is not a object, its string!!!
So you will not get name on `console.log(obj.name);`

Check like below code:

```
var args = JSON.parse('{"e":{"name":"tushar","id":"123","tag":{}}}');
obj = args.e; // Here obj is also an object.
console.log(obj.name); // so we will get name from obj
```

**JSON.stringify()** makes a object into string.

Hope you get the issue in what you are doing.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.e)) this working fine but after that its show undefined

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(args.e)); this working as per solution but after that console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.e.name)) this shows a undefined.

Comment: @TUSH: press F12 (console) & Run code snipper. check the result

Comment: when I create manually array then its working fine,but when I use args this as array then its not working

Comment: are you using `args` or `obj` as object. console.log(JSON.stringify(**args**.e)); this working. console.log(JSON.stringify(**obj**.e.name)) this shows a undefined.

Comment: sorry for miscommunication ,I got variable args in function right...Now i have done this- var obj=JSON.stringify(args.e); this gives me {
    "name": "tushar",
    "id": "123",
    "tag": {}
} then  try console.log(obj.name);

Comment: OK... `console.log(obj.name);` this will not give you as a out you desired because you have made it as a `var` (something like string).

Comment: Do you get the issue in your code now? I have updated the answer with `typeof()` & other descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for JSON.parse() instead?

You can do it with the following code:

```
 var object = JSON.parse('{"e":{"name":"tushar","id":"123","tag":{}}}');
 console.log(object.e.name); // Outputs tushar
 console.log(object.e.id); // Outputs 123
```

Comment: you must pass a string to JSON.parse(). Maybe you are doing it wrong.
How did you use it?

Comment: my function got one object,when alert this object using JSON.stringify this give array alike shown in question.

Comment: afaik, JSON.stringify will only return string. Thats why it returns undefined. You are accessing a non-existent property of a string. Why not just access it with obj.name? No need to stringify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
      var data=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      console.log(data.e);
      console.log(data.e.name);
      console.log(data.e.id);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open('GET','a.json',true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

and a.json file

`{
    "e":{
        "name":"tushar",
        "id":"123",
        "tag":{}
    }
}`